# Query to do DATEDIFF between fields on different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add a DATEDIFF to a query that gives me the hours between the current row's field, and the previous row's same field.

EDIT: {Should I ORDER the entire query by ROUTED_DTM DESC, as well as making the ORDER BY in the DATEDIFF DESC?

On one row I have a ROUTED_DTM of '2019-05-07 15:36:13.000', the row above has a ROUTED_DTM of '2019-05-01 14:19:52.000'. I would expect AGE_IN_ROLE_DAY, AGE_IN_ROLE_HR, AGE_IN_ROLE_MIN, AGE_IN_ROLE_SEC to be 6, 1, 16, and 21 (in order). However, I get 0, 0, 0, -2.}

```
SELECT c.ID,
       c.PAID_DT,
       DATEDIFF(dd,
                CASE WHEN c.ID_ADJ_FROM = '' THEN c.RECD_DT ELSE c.INPUT_DT END,
                CASE WHEN c.PAID_DT = '1/1/1753' THEN CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) ELSE c.PAID_DT END) + 1 AS DAYS_OLD
       DATEDIFF(dd, h.ROUTED_DTM, LAG(h.ROUTED_DTM) OVER (ORDER BY h.ROUTED_DTM DESC)) AS AGE_IN_ROLE_DAY,
       DATEDIFF(hh, h.ROUTED_DTM, LAG(h.ROUTED_DTM) OVER (ORDER BY h.ROUTED_DTM DESC)) AS AGE_IN_ROLE_HR,
       DATEDIFF(MM, h.ROUTED_DTM, LAG(h.ROUTED_DTM) OVER (ORDER BY h.ROUTED_DTM DESC)) AS AGE_IN_ROLE_MIN,
       DATEDIFF(ss, h.ROUTED_DTM, LAG(h.ROUTED_DTM) OVER (ORDER BY h.ROUTED_DTM DESC)) AS AGE_IN_ROLE_SEC,
       h.QUEUE_ID,
       h.QUEUE_DESC,
       h.ROLE_ID,
       h.ROLE_DESC,
       h.ROUTED_DTM

FROM table1 c
LEFT JOIN table2 h
    ON h.ID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN table 3 q
    ON q.QUEUE_ID = h.QUEUE_ID
LEFT JOIN table4 r
    ON r.ROLE_ID = h.ROLE_ID

ORDER BY c.ID, h.ROUTED_DTM DESC
```

I want to add a DATEDIFF(s) before the h.QUEUE_ID column that gives the difference between the current row's h.ROUTED_DTM, and the previous row's h.ROUTED_DTM

Currently, the query returns the correct results, however, I am not sure how to add the new DATEDIFF to each row.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no previous row unless a column contains the information.

Comment: If you are using SQL server 2012 or above, you can use LAG to get previous row's value in current row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`:

```
datediff(day, routed_dtm, lag(routed_dtm) over (order by routed_dtm))
```

You might also want `partition by c.id` in the window clause.

Comment: Edited port. Still having some issues. If you can advise, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @JEO . . . Your code does not resemble this code.  Look at the `ORDER BY`.